# phpdoc exclude multiple directory & 3 issues

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpdoc

I have 3 questions about phpdocumentor

**1.** How can I check phpdoc version I am using?? (Windows 7, XAMPP)

**2.** Is it possible to exclude multiple directories when doc generate. I have tried following but it exclude only first directory

```
 `phpdoc -d C:\xampp\htdocs\stl -t C:\xampp\htdocs\stl\docs --ignore libraries/,third_party/`
```

It excludes my `libraries` directory fine but `third_party` not excluding.

**3.** I want to upgrade my phpdocumentor. How can I do that

Answer (score 1):

**1.** In your phpDocumentor-x.x.x directory, there is a file, called `VERSION`. Open it with notepad.

**2.** Your syntax seems legit. In the [documentation](https://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/guides/running-phpdocumentor.html) it writes: `--ignore "*/tests/*,tests/*"` Maybe try to add double quotes around directories.

**3.** This is in documentation also, `pear upgrade PhpDocumentor`

Comment: +upvote. Your solutions works but partially. Now Would you please explain `*`? why & what this is? If I want to exclude 4 directory what to do then.

Second thing is My phpdoc installed both in pear as well as in C drive. Couldn't realizing which is working

Comment: Last one is not working. When run upgrade it downgrading to version 1.4.4 instead update

Comment: `*` is wildcard. It means, anything.  Try what is on the phpDocumentor page: `pear channel-discover pear.phpdoc.org` and then `pear install phpdoc/phpDocumentor`